# failed to get .ascx server control id

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

below is some sample code from my .ascx pages,i am trying to use jquery to perform someaction,  `$("input")` served me well but  `$("asp:Label")` is not working. what should I include inorder to make `$("asp:Label")` work

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvolvedMembers" runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblAcceptedBy" runat="server">    </asp:Label>
<input type="text" id="family" value="family " />
<input type="button" id="family1" value="button" />

//here i am trying to get server control to perform some action,   $("input") served me well but  $("asp:Label") is not working. what should i include inorder to make  $("asp:Label") work

$("asp:Label").hover(function() {
        Tip.text('');
        var ToolTipID = $(this).attr('id');
        var height = $(this).height() + 10;
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        if (data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1) {
            var temp = data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1;
            height = temp * 10;
        } else {
            height = 10;
        }

  $("input").hover(function() {
        Tip.text('');
        var ToolTipID = $(this).attr('id');
        var height = $(this).height() + 10;
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        if (data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1) {
            var temp = data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1;
            height = temp * 10;
        } else {
            height = 10;
        }
```

Comment: strange you have label's with `Visible="false"`?

Comment: oops, ignored it, just a sample data, i will edited it

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to change

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvolvedMembers" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

to something like

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvolvedMembers" runat="server" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
```

then you can use the jQuery selector here

```
$('.label').hover(function() {
```

instead of

```
$("asp:Label").hover(function() {
```

that way, all the labels will have the jQuery hover function.

if you wanted a specific label to be hovered, you'd have to use

```
$('#<%= lblInvolvedMembers.ClientID %>').hover(function() {
```

ASP tags are processed before being passed to the client browser where javascript can act on them, hence

`lblInvolvedMembers` would become something like `ctl0_label_lblInvolvedMembers` or something.

**UPDATE**

it also looks like you haven't closed your jQuery functions

```
$('.label').hover(function() {
        Tip.text('');
        var ToolTipID = $(this).attr('id');
        var height = $(this).height() + 10;
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        if (data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1) {
            var temp = data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1;
            height = temp * 10;
        } else {
            height = 10;
        }
});

$("input").hover(function() {
    Tip.text('');
    var ToolTipID = $(this).attr('id');
    var height = $(this).height() + 10;
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    if (data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1) {
        var temp = data[ToolTipID].split('<br\>').length - 1;
        height = temp * 10;
    } else {
        height = 10;
    }
});
```

I am not sure what `Tip` and `data` are, but you can see a working `.hover()` function on this jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/XF4Zk/ the IDs of the labels here represent a clientside id of the control created by ASP.NET, which is why you would use `lblInvolvedMembers.ClientID` to get the value of the control for Javascript

Comment: seem like this is not working in my environment, is it because i am using .ascx?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input[id$=lblInvolvedMembers]').hover(function() {
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#<%=Label.lblInvolvedMembers%>').hover();
```

or this:

```
$('#<%=Label.lblInvolvedMembers%>').hover();
```

Comment: hi dipesh, i prefer to get dynamic control id, is there any others code?

Comment: @CheemunLow if its dynamically loaded content then use .on instead of just hover..because .on works also on dynamically loaded DOM

Comment: $('#<%=Label.lblInvolvedMembers%>').on('hover',function(){});

Comment: but then it only will call lblInvolvedMembers control right? how about my lblAcceptedBy control?

Comment: @CheemunLow ohh brother i just gave example you can use it also as $('<%=Label%>').on('hover',function(){ /****/ });

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable', i got an errors

Comment: @CheemunLow do one thing add CssClass="labelCSS" in server control label and then just use $(".labelCSS").on('hover',function(){ });

Comment: seem like this is not working in my environment, is it because i am using .ascx?